# Run a script which import another module from the same root directory got no module error? (Updated)

Tags: python

I have the following directory structure

```
dir
    subdir
        a.py
        __init__.py
    tests
        e2e_tests
            test1.py
    __init__.py
```

and in `tests\e2e_tests\test1.py`

```
from subdir.a import Something
```

Then run `test1.py` in `dir`.

```
python .\tests\e2e_tests\test1.py
```

And it got the following error on `from subdir.a import Something`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\tests\e2e_tests\test1.py", line 3, in 
    from subdir.a import Something
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subdir'
```

Comment: Is `dir` intended to be a package?

Comment: no, it will be a web service.

Comment: You should delete the `__init__.py` in `dir` then. Right now, the fully qualified name for `subdir` is `dir.subdir` since that `__init__.py` makes `dir` a package.

Comment: Can you clarify where in the directory structure you intend your package to start?

Comment: Deleted `dir\__init__.py`. It still has the error though. I know change the import to `from a import Something` works. But shouldn't `from subdir.a iimport...` work too?

Comment: A python file under dir will be the entry point. But I want to be able to run util\b.py to test. Will be tests\test_abc.py in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In the folder structure I see `a.py` and `b.py` are at the same level, then you only have to do `from .a import Something` and it should work.

If you had something like this

```
subdir
    b.py
    __init__.py
a.py
__init__.py
```

Then you can user `from subdir.b import Something`note that `a.py` is outside the `subdir` folder

Comment: I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by adding the following line before the import in test1.py.

```
sys.path.insert(1, os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/../..')
```

Is there a better solution?